# What am I misunderstanding about the Liskov Substitution Principle

Tags: php, liskov-substitution-principle

I thought I understand the LSP, but it seems I'm totally wrong. I have the following classes:

```
class PrimitiveValue {
}

class StringValue extends PrimitiveValue {
}

class A {
    public function foo(StringValue $value) {
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function foo(PrimitiveValue $value) {
    }
}
```

---

Note that the base class A accepts the *subclass* StringValue as a parameter type, and the subclass B accepts the parent class PrimitiveValue. I'm saying this because a similar question, just with reversed types, gets being asked everywhere.

According to my understanding, the method foo() in class B accepts anything that the parent method accepts, plus more, since it accepts the base type PrimitiveValue. Thus, any caller who just sees class A passes values that can be handled by B, not violating the LSP. Callers who know that it is a B can make stronger assumptions and are free to pass other PrimitiveValue subtypes.

Yet when I execute the code, I get the error:

Strict (2048): Declaration of B::foo() should be compatible with A::foo(StringValue $value) [APP/Controller/TestLocalController.php, line 17]

What am I getting wrong? I think most helpful would be an example of how a value can be passed that violates the assumptions the code makes about that value. Assuming that it is clear what I'm trying to achieve, please also add code on how to do it correctly.

Comment: The problem is that strict standards don't let you change the signature of a method that you're over-riding in an extended class, so `foo()` in `B` must have the same signature as `foo()` in `A`. This is a basic PHP restriction. Change the signature of `foo()` in `B` to `public function foo(StringValue $value) {`

Comment: Generally you're not wrong, though I would argue that it's not necessarily good practice to overload an inherited method so it will accept a type that its parent does not. What about `parent::foo($value)`? You should make that a different method then. From an LSP perspective it's not incorrect; it's debatable whether PHP tries to look out for you and enforce best practices here, or whether PHP is simply not implementing the LSP check to the extend that it should/could.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more suited to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: It doesn't violate LSP but method overrides in PHP are type invariant (iirc) which is why this is not allowed ... that said, it doesn't seem like you should be doing this ;-)

Comment: @Mark Baker: If there is a PHP restriction and/or I'm not expected to do that, then what is the proper way to solve the problem?

Comment: @deceze: Why isn't that good practice? Calling parent::foo() is obviously invalid unless you have made sure that the parameter is a StringValue (e.g. by instanceof). In my case, A and B are interfaces anyway, so there is no parent::foo().

Comment: Because it makes things more complicated. Just because you *can* use inheritance in certain ways doesn't mean you should be using the heck out of it. Keep your type system as simple as possible.

Comment: actually this is a technical question about a code bug so it is a fit for SO, not programmers.SE. Though there's more than a few good questions about LSP on programmers, this one being about a specific PHP implementation that seems to have bugs is more specific and better for SO I'd say.

Comment: Some of the comments below have stated that doing this is useless or not recommended. Some information about this would be nice, since I encountered the problem in a real-world example where A and B are actually comparator interfaces (like Comparator in Java) that I want to use as widely as possible. So it doesn't seem useless or "dirty" at all to me.

Comment: Some other comments basically say, that's not how I'm supposed to do this in PHP. How am I supposed to solve the problem in PHP then? I cannot change the signature of the method in B, as class B then couldn't handle all values it could handle and for which I want to use it. Nor can I use type parameters like I would do in Java.

Comment: Sorry about adding this as a comment. I tried adding these things to the question, but they disappeared and are marked as deleted in the edit history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I getting wrong? 
>   I think most helpful would be an example of how a value can be passed that violates the assumptions the code makes about that value.

You didn't misunderstand LSP, allowing a bigger type in a subclassed method doesn't violate the principle; in fact, what you've described is known as [contravariant method argument types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Contravariant_method_argument_type), something which is not supported in PHP either by design or implementation difficulties.

Personally, my only reservation about this approach is that handling of the weaker type within your subclass is hidden by the superclass.

> Assuming that it is clear what I'm trying to achieve, please also add code on how to do it correctly.

Method argument types in PHP are invariant, i.e. the type for each argument (if supplied in the parent) must match exactly when overriding a method. While this behaviour has been discussed in the [past](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/prototype_checks) and brought up again [recently](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=internals@lists.php.net&q=subject:%22Re%3A%20%5BPHP-DEV%5D%20%5BRFC%5D%5BDiscussion%5D%20Return%20Type%20Variance%20Checking%22&o=newest&f=1) with the introduction of [return type hinting](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/return_types), it's not guaranteed to be available even in the next major version.

To overcome this, you're currently forced to making both primitive and derived types implement the same interface and then use that in both parent and child classes, as described by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28362364/1338292).

Answer (score 1):

That's not how PHP OOP works. You can do it using interfaces, as such:

```
<?php

interface CommonInterface {
}

class PrimitiveValue implements CommonInterface {
}

class StringValue extends PrimitiveValue implements CommonInterface {
}

class A {
    public function foo(CommonInterface $value) {
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function foo(CommonInterface $value) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Interfaces are nice, but this doesn't actually answer the question.  The OP was asking why he couldn't make the subclass method take a superclass as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, given the pieces you have shown, there's no situation in which you could produce an error stemming from incompatible types. However, who's saying that's going to be the final class structure? You may divorce `StringValue` from `PrimitiveValue` in the future. The method signature must be compatible "by itself", to avoid such future failure if you change seemingly unrelated code. Just looking at the signatures themselves they're *obviously incompatible.* Only with the additional knowledge of two other classes can the signatures *be thought of as* compatible. That's too much cross-coupling; that's "compatibility by proxy". Types are more loosely coupled than that. The type name in a type hint does not infer an implementation. Your "compatibility" only stems from the current implementation of your types, but not from the type signatures themselves.

Your signatures are *different*, therefore incompatible. You cannot make any guarantees about the current or future compatibility of those signatures. Nowhere is it formally specified that `StringValue` and `PrimitiveValue` have any compatible relationship. You may have *a* current *implementation* that says so, but the type signature cannot know that or rely on that.

As a practical example, this works:

```
require 'my_types.php'; // imports StringValue

(new B)->foo(new StringValue);
```

This doesn't:

```
require 'my_alternative_type_implementations.php'; // imports StringValue

(new B)->foo(new StringValue);  // fatal error: expected PrimitiveValue
```

Nothing changed about the type signatures in `B`, yet it still broke during execution.

Comment: "Just looking at the signatures themselves they're obviously incompatible." -- why? "Only with the additional knowledge of two other classes can the signatures be thought of as compatible" -- the same could be said about calling a method of an object which the object's class doesn't declare, only inherit. Why is the latter legal then?

Comment: They're obviously incompatible because they're different types. Boom. Nothing more, nothing less. PHP doesn't think much further than that. And as I hopefully explained, maybe that's a good thing. :)

Comment: As it's not a violation of the LSP, I don't think anything about this is "obvious". Anyway, the question is still open: What is the *proper* way to handle this in PHP?